# Vagrant : reusing a puppet_server block for multiple VMs

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have a Vagrantfile with two VMs defined. I want to provision those using a puppet master. When I had just a single VM I could use

```
config.vm.provision "puppet_server" do |puppet|
 puppet.puppet_server           = "puppet.srv"
 puppet.puppet_node             =  config.vm.hostname
 puppet.client_cert_path        = "../puppet/ssl/ca/signed/#{config.vm.hostname}.pem"
 puppet.client_private_key_path = "#{config.vm.hostname}.key"
 puppet.options                 = "--test"
end
```

I would like to reuse this block for both VMs, but can't since the client_cert_path and client_private_key_path need to be different for each VM.

When I try to execute the Vagrantfile with these settings I get

> There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
>   the following errors and try again:
>
> puppet server provisioner:
>
> - The specified client cert path could not be found
> - The specified client private key path could not be found
> - "puppet_node" is required when a client cert or key is specified

which leads me to believe that `config.vm.hostname` is undefined

How can I achieve this without duplicating the code block?

Comment: If you do not include the puppet block in one of the 2 vm block, it should be applied by default to both VM so you do not need to duplicate for each VM block

Comment: I believe that you can do whatever you can imagine using Ruby syntax in that context. So basically you want this block to behave slightly different depending on some property of each VM (isn't this already the case since you're expanding the `config.vm.hostname` variable?)

Comment: @FelixFrank - I tried with that exact config, and `config.vm.hostname` is not expanded - I'll paste the error message in the question body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a `Helper` class after the `Vagrant.configure` block:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# regular configuration here
end

class Helper
  def self.provision_puppet(vm)
    vm.provision "puppet_server" do |puppet|
      puppet.puppet_server            = "puppet.test"
      puppet.puppet_node              =  vm.hostname
      puppet.client_cert_path         = "../puppet/ssl/ca/signed/#{vm.hostname}.pem"
      puppet.client_private_key_path  = "ssl/#{vm.hostname}.key"
      puppet.options                  = "--test"
    end
  end
end
```

and then invoked `Helper.provision_vm` for each of the vms

```ruby
config.vm.define "vpn", autostart: false do |vpn|
  # various configurations
  Helper.provision_puppet vpn.vm
end
```